# need to create dotted line instead of dashed lines in android

Tags: android

This code gives me a dashed line (--------------------) but what i want is a dotted line (.........................).
The code below using with list view gives a dash line as a line separator but i want a dotted line.
Is there a way to achieve this.

dotted.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <size
    android:height="4dp"
    android:width="700dp"/>

<stroke
   android:dashWidth="3px"
   android:color="@android:color/black"
   android:dashGap="3px"/>
```

Comment: android:dashWidth="1px"

Comment: @Tirath but then i can't increase the size of the dots..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to increase the size of the dot is setting the width of stroke as same as dashWidth.

```
<stroke
    android:width="4dp"
    android:dashWidth="4dp"
    android:dashGap="8dp"
/>
```

Comment: dots disappeared after using this

Comment: Hm... What do you mean disappearing? In that case, you may check the color of stroke, or if the line looks like just a thick solid line..

One tricky thing is if you are running the app over ICS, you should set the view's layoutType as 'software' in order to display dotted line correctly.
    `<View
        android:layerType="software"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`